# Unable read data from Socket

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-builder

I have a flash AS3 file which interacts with a socket server, server sends data as plain text. I am unable to read the data whats being send from the server using Socket class. Code what I am using in flash is below.

```
var socket:Socket = new Socket("localhost", 9231);

socket.addEventListener(Event.CONNECT, socketConnectHandler, false, 0, true);
socket.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA, socketDataHandler, false, 0, true);

function socketConnectHandler(event:Event):void{
    trace("Connection has been established ");
}

function socketDataHandler(event:ProgressEvent):void{   
    var stream:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    socket.writeBytes(stream, 0, 0);
    trace(stream.readUTF());
    trace( socket.readUTF());
}
```

I get below error for while I try to read ByteArray and socket data being send.

```
Error: Error #2030: End of file was encountered.
    at flash.net::Socket/readUTF()
    at socket_test_fla::MainTimeline/socketDataHandler()
```

I have tried various combinations to get it working without success. Any clue to help me understand the issue and find a fix would be grateful.

Update:

I modified code given by @t to

```
var stream:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
socket.writeBytes(stream, 0, 0);

var data:String = "";
while(socket.bytesAvailable > 0) {
  data += socket.readByte();
}

trace("data "+ data);
```

I get trace as "0124661171161161111109579756184114117101124-1" or similar bunch of numbers. Any idea to convert these codes to respective characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I got it working... Thanks all for the help. Below is the code that worked for me.

```
var socket:Socket = new Socket("localhost", 2553);

socket.addEventListener(Event.CONNECT, socketConnectHandler, false, 0, true);
socket.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA, socketDataHandler, false, 0, true);

function socketConnectHandler(event:Event):void{
    trace("Connection has been established ");
}

function socketDataHandler(event:ProgressEvent):void{   

    var stream:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    socket.writeBytes(stream, 0, 0);

    var data:String = "";

    while(socket.bytesAvailable){
        data += socket.readUTFBytes(1);
    }   

    trace("data "+ data);   
}
```

Comment: `socket.writeBytes(stream, 0, 0);` line is useless you don't send anything with it. Maybe you are not getting any data from the server because you haven't sent anything in the first place. (it depends what kind of server it is).

Answer (score 1):

End of file means there is not enough data available for reading.

```
var data:String = "";
while(socket.bytesAvailable > 0) {
    data += socket.readUTF();
}
```

And you are trying to read also empty "stream" ByteArray.

Comment: ByteArray is not empty, I have already checked for that. This code also throws the same error. Probably need to study more about bytes and ByteArray. Thanks Taanielo!!